# jquery AJAX and webservices using onchange for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a dropdownlist that I use jquery ajax to make a call to a webmethod. My intended solution is to update all the data fields on the cuurent page based on the dropdown selected index using ajax.

```
function getDBInfo()
{

   var mySelectedIndex = $("#<%=dblParameter.ClientID%>").val(); //id name for dropdown list
   $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"/Manage/Details.aspx?param=",
         data:{}
         contentType:application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType:"json"
         success: function(data)
         {
             //this is what I am trying to accomplish but not sure how I should handle the webservice method to do this or if I am even doing it right so far
             $("#<%=txtParameter.ClientID%>;").text(data.Parameter);
             $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>;").text(data.Name);
             $("#<%=txtSSN.ClientID%>;").text(data.SSN);
             //etc....
         }
     });
 }
```

then in my code behind I have my page method

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    dblParameter.Attributes.Add("onchange","getDBInfo");
 }
 [WebMethod]
 public static DataRowView getDBInfo(string param)
 {                 
     ConnectionStringSettings conn = ConfiguationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterDBConnectionString"];
     SQLDataSource Details = new SqlDataSource(conn.ConnectionString, "SELECT * FROM [tblInfo] WHERE ([ParamID] = "+param);
     DataRowView db = (DataRowView)Details.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
      return db;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong because in my javascript calling data.Name or data.Parameter won't work. Should it be data["Parameter"] instead? or am I way off base here

**Edit1:**

I changed a lot of my code around here is what I have and I am **now its working**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#<%=dblParameter.ClientID%>").change(function(){
     var myparam= $("#<%=dblParameter.ClientID%>").val(); //id name for dropdown list
       $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"Details.aspx/getDBInfo",
         data:'{param:"'+myparam+'"}',
         contentType:application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function(data)
         {
             alert(data.d)
         }
     });
   });
 });

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
 [WebMethod]
 public static string getDBInfo(string param)
 {                 
     MyMainClass myInit = new MyMainClass();
     string target= myInit.GetInfo(param);
     return target;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#<%=dblParameter.ClientID%>").change(function(){ 
     var myparam= $("#<%=dblParameter.ClientID%>").val(); //id name for dropdown list       
     $.ajax({ 
      type:"POST",
      url:"Details.aspx/getDBInfo",
      data:'{param:"'+myparam+'"}',
      contentType:application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data)
      {       
       alert(data.d)
      } 
  }); 
 });
});  
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
 } 
[WebMethod]
public static string getDBInfo(string param)  { 
     MyMainClass myInit = new MyMainClass();
     string target= myInit.GetInfo(param);
  return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net will wrap your data in a "d" object. This is the case with all ASMX services serialized through the ASP.NET. Even if you are returning a single string value, it will always be wrapped in a "d" object.

You can solve your problem by changing your Success callback to the following:

```
$("#<%=txtParameter.ClientID%>;").text(data.d.Parameter);
$("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>;").text(data.d.Name);
$("#<%=txtSSN.ClientID%>;").text(data.d.SSN);
```

You can ready more about this here: [A breaking change between versions of ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about json but u can use that way.
debug the 'result' to see what is in.

```
function getDBInfo()
{
// GET UR WEBMETHOD PARAM: SUPPOSE X

PageMethods.getDBInfo(X, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
}

// Callback function invoked on successful completion of the page method.
function OnSucceeded(result, methodName) {
if (result != null && result != '')
   // do whatever
else
    //do whatever
}

// Callback function invoked on failure of the page method.
function OnFailed(error, methodName) {
if (error != null) {
    // do whatever
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function getDBInfo() {
    var mySelectedIndex = $('#<%=dblParameter.ClientID%>').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Manage/Details.aspx',
        data: JSON.stringify({ param: mySelectedIndex }),
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         success: function(data) {
             $('#<%=txtParameter.ClientID%>').text(data.d.Parameter);
             $('#<%=txtName.ClientID%>').text(data.d.Name);
             $('#<%=txtSSN.ClientID%>').text(data.d.SSN);
         }
    });
}
```

Also make sure that the object that you are returnign from your page method has Parameter, Name and SSN properties which are used in the success callback. You are returning a DataRowView and I doubt it has such properties. Define and use a strongly typed class in this case which will be returned from your page method.

Also notice the usage of the `JSON.stringify` method to send the JSON request. This method is natively built-in modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you will need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page as well.

You will also notice other modifications that I did to your code:

- Removed unnecessary `;` after your server side expressions inside the jQuery selectors
- Removed the `dataType: 'json'` from the AJAX call => it's unnecessary, jQuery is intelligent enough to deduce it from the server Content-Type response header.
- Quoted correctly the `contentType` parameter in your ajax call.
- Added `.d` to the `data` parameter passed to the `success` callback. It's an ASP.NET stuff which wraps the entire JSON response with this `d` property: `{ d: ...... }`

I would also recommend you reading the [following article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) about invoking ASP.NET PageMethods/Script WebMethods with jQuery.

Comment: since I need to create a strongly type dataobject with the properties, I think I am going to go that route by creating LinqToSql classes to get a feel of that since im want to expand my knowledge in LinqtoSql. does that change anything above? besides my webmethod

Comment: @Jake, no, only the return type and the implementation of the web method are impacted.

Comment: I made the necessary changes and now I am receiving the error 'Json is undefined' ad after some googling I found out that I have to add the json2.js file in my project. is that accurate and are the other alternatives to that. P.S. Im using IE7

Comment: @Jake, yes IE7 doesn't support the `JSON.stringify` method natively. IE7 is considered as legacy browser (it's like 2 generations behind the latest stable version - IE9). So you need to include `json2.js` to your page.

Comment: @Jake, yes, you could write your own JSON parser. But more seriously, use what jQuery recommend which is json2.js.

Comment: For some reason the JSON is undefined error is still there after adding the json2 file. The intellisense for it works so it does the the reference. Not sure whats going on